# Is a Modal Confirm Box Using JQuery Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Looked around quite a bit, and can't seem to find a JQuery solution (*maybe its just a limitation of JavaScript*) for this:

```
<a href="somelink.php" 
   onclick="return confirm('Go to somelink.php?');">Click Here</a>
```

In the above example, when a user clicks on the link, it will only go to its href if the user clicks OK in the confirm box.

What I am trying to do is get a more modern look using a popup div. Perhaps something like this:

```
<a href="somelink.php" 
   onclick="return jq_confirm('Go to somelink.php?');">Click Here</a>
```

(Where **jq_confirm** is a custom JQuery confirm function that pops up a nice div with a YES/NO or OK/CANCEL button pair).

**However, I cannot seem to find any such thing.**

I have looked at some JQuery widget libraries etc which offer similar functionality, but none will wait for the response from the user (*at least, not in the scenario described above*), but instead they just proceed and take the user to the link (*or run any JavaScript embedded in the href='' piece of the link*). I suspect this is because while you can attach a callback function to many of these widgets to return a true/false value, the **onclick** event does not wait for a response (*callbacks are asynchronous*), thereby defeating the purpose of the confirm box.

What I need is the same kind of halt-all-javascript (modal) functionality that the default **confirm()** command provides. Is this possible in JQuery (*or even in JavaScript*)?

As I am not an expert in JavaScript nor in JQuery, I defer to you gurus out there. Any JQuery (*or even pure JavaScript*) solution is welcome (*if possible*).

Thanks -

Comment: I have the similer question..! will wait for someone to reply your question..!

Answer (score 21):

I just had to solve the same problem.  I wound up using the [`dialog`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) widget from [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home).  I was able to implement this without using callbacks with the caveat that the `dialog` must be partially initialized in the `click` event handler for the link you want to use the confirmation functionality with (if you want to use this for more than one link).  This is because the target URL for the link must be injected into the event handler for the confirmation button click.

Here's my solution, abstracted away to be suitable for an example.  I use a CSS class to indicate which links should have the confirmation behavior.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required">
  Are you sure about this?
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true
    });

  $(".confirmLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

    $("#dialog").dialog({
      buttons : {
        "Confirm" : function() {
          window.location.href = targetUrl;
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });




  }); // end of $(document).ready


</script>

<a class="confirmLink" href="http://someLinkWhichRequiresConfirmation.com">Click here</a>
<a class="confirmLink" href="http://anotherSensitiveLink">Or, you could click here</a>
```

Comment: I wonder why this solution got accepted (and 12 upvotes). The answer to OP question is: there is no such thing which stops all javascript processing like confirm. The surprisingly accepted solution would (i'm guessing) probably randomly execute some onclick events if there are any. Probably depending on the browser as well. The whole confirmation dialog replacement seems to have no clean solution.

Comment: Absolutely agree with Toskan. Also, those users with js disabled will not get directed to anywhere if you simply rely on js based click events. However, I guess this is exactly why you are going for this, no?

Answer (score 7):

Check out http://www.84bytes.com/2008/06/02/jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/

They have a good variety of modal-boxes for JQuery.

I think you should see http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal/

> A modal dialog override of the JavaScript confirm function. Demonstrates the use of onShow as well as how to display a modal dialog confirmation instead of the default JavaScript confirm dialog.

Comment: I evaluated that very same code, but it did not work for the scenario I describe. Problem is, I have hundreds of these confirm() codes thru a site coded as I describe, and would rather just do a simple replace -> confirm() with jq_confirm than have to carefully recode all href and onclick code throughout hundreds of pages (if it's possible, that is).

Answer (score 7):

Did you see the [jQuery Modal Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) on [jQuery UI site](http://jqueryui.com/)?

- **[Modal Confirmation Dialog demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)**

Comment: Thanks, lotsof  dodgy plugins came up on my Googling - this is what I needed!

Comment: @Toskan - I read the question as the OP wanting to be able to style and effectively customize the dialog that comes up with `confirm()`. Since the styling is browser-specific, the OP will need to resort to a client-side script implementation of a dialog box, which is what I am recommending. How does this not solve the confirmation problem?

Comment: Dear RussCam: well it shows a box where you can press some buttons - but that's not what OP was asking for. He was asking for a javascript which stops event execution until confirmed / canceled. The accepted solution (with 12 up-votes) is imho evil. The show stopper is imho that you basically break and drop dead all click events and bam redirect somewhere else. Secondly imagine OP decides to use confirm on submit buttons. Take a big sword and cut down all events in all places for a confirm box? What about a clean solution?

Answer (score 6):

I blogged about the solution to this issue here: http://markmintoff.com/2011/03/asp-net-jquery-confirm-dialog/

Even though the article is geared towards ASP.Net it can be easily adapted to php. It relies on preventing the click with a return false and when the user clicks "OK" or "YES" or what-have-you; the link or button is simply clicked again.

```
var confirmed = false;
function confirmDialog(obj)
{
    if(!confirmed)
    {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function()
                {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    confirmed = true; obj.click();
                },
                "No": function()
                {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return confirmed;
}
```

Give it a try and let me know what you think. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Brilliant, this is the the only answer I've seen that returns a boolean (as originally asked), paste the code in Mark?

Comment: brilliant. it saves me some ugly hacks.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to override the standard window.confirm function be writing the following code.

```
window.confirm = modalConfirm
```

then you will need to make a function like this

```
function modalConfirm(message){
  // put your code here and bind "return true/false" to the click event
  // of the "Yes/No" buttons.
}
```

This should work, although I haven't tested it yet. I am going to do exactly this right now and will let you all know how it worked.

Edit:
I have tested my example above now and it was not possible, you will have to pass in a callback function to your overwritten confirm function like this:

```
function modalConfirm(message, callback){
  ... 
  $("button.yes").click(function(){
     callback(result);
  });
  ...
}
```

..making your call to the function look like this:

```
confirm("Are you sure?", function(result){
  alert(result);
});
```

In other words, it is not possible to completely override the default window.confirm function without causing a nasty loop that causes the browser to hang. I think that you will have to modify your confirm calls like above.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question seems to be missing the canonical answer: **there is no way to programatically pause (and resume) javascript execution like `alert` or `confirm` do**.

That being said, relying on this behaviour today is usually considered bad practice given the single threaded nature of javascript, and the reason why the aforementioned functions do pause execution is probably because they were designed when the web was still at a very early stage, and later left unchanged to ensure compatibility. Since the focus nowadays is in writing as much non-blocking js code as possible, it's unlikely the functionality to programmatically halt js will ever make it to any future specification of ECMAScript, so your best bet is to rework your site to make sure confirm and alert dialogs can co-exist with other javascript code running in the background.

Comment: Confirm doesn't pause the script, at least not on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Put the redirect inside the function like:

```
<script>
    function confirmRedirect(url, desciption) {
       if (confirmWindow(desciption)) {
           window.location = url;
       }
    }
</script>
```

And call it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:confirmRedirect('somlink.php','Are you sure?')">Go!</a>
```

Comment: I would suggest not using the javascript:function() inline code, as it does not degrade well when javascript is disabled.  The link will do nothing if that is the case.  Instead use  <a href="somelocation" onclick="myFunc();return false">click here</a> or <a href="#" onclick="myFunc();return false">click here</a> as done in the original question.

Comment: Problem is, I have hundreds of these confirm() codes thru a site coded as I describe, and would rather just do a simple replace -> confirm() with jq_confirm than have to carefully recode all href and onclick code throughout hundreds of pages (if it's possible, that is).

Comment: Users w/out javascript = who cares

Answer (score 1):

My way around this problem was to add some arbitrary data to the object, and check for that data on click. If it existed, proceed with the function as normal, otherwise confirm with a yes/no (in my case using a jqtools overlay). If the user clicks yes - insert the data in the object, simulate another click and wipe the data. If they click no, just close the overlay.

Here is my example:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    if ($(this).data('confirmed')) {
        // Do stuff
    } else {
        confirm($(this));
    }
});
```

And this is what I did to override the confirm function (using a jquery tools overlay):

```
window.confirm = function(obj){
    $('#dialog').html('\
        <div>\
            <h2>Confirm</h2>\
            <p>Are you sure?</p>\
            <p>\
                <button name="confirm" value="yes" class="facebox-btn close">Yes</button>\
                <button name="confirm" value="no" class="facebox-btn close">No</button>\
            </p>\
        </div>').overlay().load();
    $('button[name=confirm]').click(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
            $('#dialog').overlay().close();
            obj.data('confirmed', true).click().removeData('confirmed');
        } else {
            $('#dialog').overlay().close();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of Banu's solution (thanks a ton!) to make it a one pop solution on top of each page.  Paste this code inside:

```
$(document).ready
```

And add "confirmLinkFollow" class to all links you want confirmed:

```
$(".confirmLinkFollow").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
var $dialog_link_follow_confirm = $('<div></div>').
        html("<p>Are you sure?</p>").
        dialog({autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Please Confirm',
        buttons : {
            "Confirm" : function() { 
                window.location.href = targetUrl; 
        },
        "Cancel" : function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            }
        },

        modal: true,
    minWidth: 250,
    minHeight: 120
    }
    );


    $dialog_link_follow_confirm.dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that can be used to replace the default window.confirm function. It doesn't require you overriding window.confirm as that is not fully possible.

My solution allows you to have a general class like me, let's say 'confirm-action' that you place on any element that requires a confirmation before being processed. The script is very simple and utilizes jQuery, jQuery UI Dialog and no other plugins.

You can find the complete demo of the implementation on jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/74NDD/39/.

Usage:

- Add this javascript code in your html head or before any other click
  binding you have in your javascript.

  ```
  $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

  $('.confirm-action').live('click', function(e) {
      $self = $(this);

      if (e && e.stopImmediatePropagation && $self.data('confirmed') !== true) {
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();

          $('#confirm-action-dialog').dialog({
              height: 110,
              modal: true,
              resizable: false,
              draggable: false,
              buttons: {
                  'Yes': function() {
                      $(this).dialog('close');
                      $self.data('confirmed', true);
                      $self.click();
                  },
                  'No': function() {
                      $self.data('confirmed', false);
                      $(this).dialog('close');
                  }
              }
          });
      } else if ($self.data('confirmed') === true) {
          e = window.event;
          e.cancelBubble = false;
          $self.data('confirmed', false);
      }

      return false;
  });
  ```
- Place this html somewhere in the body (it is hidden by default).

  ```
  <div style="display:none;" id="confirm-action-dialog" title="Confirm Action?">
      <p>
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span>
          Are you sure you want to continue?
      </p>
  </div>
  ```
- Put the class 'confirm-action' on any element that requires confirmation.

  ```
  confirm-action
  ```

This solution works perfect as it does not alter jQuery event bubbling, it merely pauses (stops) all other events until the user decides what they want to do.

I hope this is helpful for someone else as I was unable to find any other solution that doesn't require me installing another jQuery plugin or do some other hack.

Answer (score 0):

The following link has a jQuery plugin for confirm boxes similar to constructing like confirm("something") in JavaScript

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Answer (score 0):

Almost three years later, I am looking for something similar. Since I have not found an acceptable "quick" solution, I wrote something that comes very close to the criteria of the OP. I figure others may find it useful in the future.

JavaScript is event-driven and that means it does not support any sort of "wait" or "sleep" loop that we can use to pause a pure-javascript confirm function. The options involve burning processor cycles, using a browser plugin, or AJAX. In our increasingly mobile world, and with sometimes spotty internet connections, none of these are great solutions. This means that we have to return from our "confirm" function immediately.

However, since there is no "false" logic in the code snippet above (ie. nothing is done when the user clicks "Cancel"), we can trigger the "click" or "submit" event again when the user clicks "OK." Why not set a flag and react based on that flag within our "confirm" function?

For my solution, I opted to use FastConfirm rather than a "modal" dialog. You can easily modify the code to use anything you want but my example was designed to use this:

https://github.com/pjparra/Fast-Confirm

Due to the nature of what this does, I do not see a clean way to package it up. If you feel that this has too many rough edges, feel free to smooth them out or rewrite your code the way that everyone else has recommended:

```
/* This version of $.fn.hasEvent is slightly modified to provide support for
 * the "onclick" or "onsubmit" tag attributes. I chose this because it was
 * short, even if it is cryptic.
 *
 * Learn more about the code by Sven Eisenschmidt, which is licensed under
 * the MIT and GPL at:
 *     http://github.com/fate/jquery-has-event
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasEvent = function(A, F, E) {
        var L = 0;
        var T = typeof A;
        E = E ? E : this;
        var V = (E.attr('on'+A) != undefined);
        A = (T == 'string') ? $.trim(A) : A;
        if (T == 'function')
            F = A, A = null;
        if (F == E)
            delete(F);
        var S = E.data('events');
        for (e in S)
            if (S.hasOwnProperty(e))
                L++;
        if (L < 1)
            return V; // = false;
        if (A && !F) {
            return V = S.hasOwnProperty(A);
        } else if(A && S.hasOwnProperty(A) && F) {
            $.each(S[A], function(i, r) {
                if(V == false && r.handler == F) V = true;
            });
            return V;
        } else if(!A && F) {
            $.each(S, function(i, s) {
                if (V == false) {
                    $.each(s, function(k, r) {
                        if (V == false && r.handler == F)
                            V = true;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        return V;
    }
    $.extend($, {hasEvent: $.fn.hasEvent});
}) (jQuery);

/* Nearly a drop-in replacement for JavaScript's confirm() dialog.
 * Syntax:
 *   onclick="return jq_confirm(this, 'Are you sure that you want this?', 'right');"
 *
 * NOTE: Do not implement "false" logic when using this function. Find another way.
 */
var jq_confirm_bypass = false;
function jq_confirm(el, question, pos) {
    var override = false;
    var elem = $(el);

    if ($.fn.fastConfirm == undefined) {
        override = confirm(question);
    } else if (!jq_confirm_bypass) {
        if (pos == undefined) {
            pos = 'right';
        }

        elem.fastConfirm({
            position: pos,
            questionText: question,
            onProceed: function(trigger) {
                var elem = $(trigger);
                elem.fastConfirm('close');

                if (elem.hasEvent('click')) {
                    jq_confirm_bypass = true;
                    elem.click();
                    jq_confirm_bypass = false;
                }
                if (elem.hasEvent('submit')) {
                    jq_confirm_bypass = true;
                    elem.submit();
                    jq_confirm_bypass = false;
                }
                // TODO: ???
            },
            onCancel: function(trigger) {
                $(trigger).fastConfirm('close');
            }
        });
    }

    return override ? override : jq_confirm_bypass;
}
```

So... onclick="return confirm('Do you want to test this?');" would become onclick="return jq_confirm(this, 'Do you want to test this?');" The pos/"right" parameter is optional and is specifically for Fast-Confirm.

When you click, the jq_confirm() function will spawn the jQuery dialog and return "false." When the user clicks "OK" then jq_confirm() sets a flag, calls the original click (or submit) event, returns "true", then unsets the flag in case you want to remain on the same page.