# How to implement "confirmation" dialog in Jquery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

I am try to use JQuery UI Dialog to replace the ugly `javascript:alert()` box.
In my scenario, I have a list of items, and next to each individual of them, I would have a "delete" button for each of them. 
the psuedo html setup will be something follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>ITEM <a href="url/to/remove"> <span>$itemId</span>
    <li>ITEM <a href="url/to/remove"><span>$itemId</span>
    <li>ITEM <a href="url/to/remove"><span>$itemId</span>
</ul>

<div id="confirmDialog">Are you sure?</div>
```

In JQ part, on document ready, I would first setup the div to be a modal dialog with necessary button, and set those "a" to be firing to confirmation before to remove, like:

```
$("ul li a").click(function() {
  // Show the dialog    
  return false; // to prevent the browser actually following the links!
}
```

OK, here's the problem. during the init time, the dialog will have no idea who (item) will fire it up, and also the item id (!). How can I setup the behavior of those confirmation buttons in order to, if the user still choose YES, it will follow the link to remove it?

Comment: There is a easy to use plugin to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457750/form-confirm-before-submit

Comment: Looooong searched for solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18474005/1876355

Answer (score 169, accepted):

I just had to solve the same problem.  The key to getting this to work was that the `dialog` must be partially initialized in the `click` event handler for the link you want to use the confirmation functionality with (if you want to use this for more than one link).  This is because the target URL for the link must be injected into the event handler for the confirmation button click.  I used a CSS class to indicate which links should have the confirmation behavior.

Here's my solution, abstracted away to be suitable for an example.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required">
  Are you sure about this?
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true
    });
  });

  $(".confirmLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

    $("#dialog").dialog({
      buttons : {
        "Confirm" : function() {
          window.location.href = targetUrl;
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
</script>

<a class="confirmLink" href="http://someLinkWhichRequiresConfirmation.com">Click here</a>
<a class="confirmLink" href="http://anotherSensitiveLink">Or, you could click here</a>
```

I believe that this would work for you, if you can generate your links with the CSS class (`confirmLink`, in my example).

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Raitono/jcxv8qom/1/) with the code in it.

In the interest of full disclosure, I'll note that I spent a few minutes on this particular problem and I provided a similar answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878710/is-a-modal-confirm-box-using-jquery-possible), which was also without an accepted answer at the time.

Comment: +1 almost works...  but see answer from @lloydphillips for a correction

Comment: Does anyone else notice that this will cause a full PostBack inside an UpdatePanel? How do you fix that?

Comment: There's something about this answer and @lloydphillips' answers that just doesn't quite do it for me.  The original question is in reference to a "delete" button (link).  In general, it is inadvisable to use a link (HTTP GET) for an operation which changes state (such as a DELETE).  Both of these answers assume that the user has javascript enabled.  If javascript is disabled, the links will fire and the delete (or whatever other) operation will fire without confirmation, which could be catastrophic. I was hoping to find an answer which dealt with this issue.

Comment: @echo: I thought about the same. To make it proper I think there has to be another page that asks for confirmation if JS is disabled. If JS this page could be omitted. Maybe through another get parameter like confirmed=true. Really hard and cumbersome to take cases with and without JS into account. Web development is a mess.

Comment: Is there any way available to change the id of this dialog so that we can use more than one such dialogs?

Comment: @sree Sure.  You could extract a function that took the name of the id to use as a parameter and made the jQuery calls to set up the event handlers for the passed-in id.

Comment: jsfiddle link returns 404

Answer (score 60):

I found the answer by Paul didn't quite work as the way he was setting the options AFTER the dialog was instantiated on the click event were incorrect. Here is my code which was working. I've not tailored it to match Paul's example but it's only a cat's whisker's difference in terms of some elements are named differently. You should be able to work it out. The correction is in the setter of the dialog option for the buttons on the click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        bgiframe: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 200,
        autoOpen: false
    });


    $(".lb").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var theHREF = $(this).attr("href");

        $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'buttons', {
            "Confirm" : function() {
                window.location.href = theHREF;
            },
            "Cancel" : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        });

        $("#dialog").dialog("open");

    });

});
```

Hope this helps someone else as this post originally got me down the right track I thought I'd better post the correction.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you did that was different than Paul's answer.

Comment: Looks good to me. The only thing I would sugest would be to use `on` instead of `click`, as this will continue to work if (for example) the field is redrawn using jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: hah "cat's whisker's difference" -- I need to use that phrase more.

Answer (score 28):

I've created a my own function for a jquery ui confirm dialog.
Here is the code

```
function myConfirm(dialogText, okFunc, cancelFunc, dialogTitle) {
  $('<div style="padding: 10px; max-width: 500px; word-wrap: break-word;">' + dialogText + '</div>').dialog({
    draggable: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: 'auto',
    title: dialogTitle || 'Confirm',
    minHeight: 75,
    buttons: {
      OK: function () {
        if (typeof (okFunc) == 'function') {
          setTimeout(okFunc, 50);
        }
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
      },
      Cancel: function () {
        if (typeof (cancelFunc) == 'function') {
          setTimeout(cancelFunc, 50);
        }
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Now to use this in your code, simply write following

```
myConfirm('Do you want to delete this record ?', function () {
    alert('You clicked OK');
  }, function () {
    alert('You clicked Cancel');
  },
  'Confirm Delete'
);
```

Go on.

Comment: This is a good solution, it's very similar to mine that I use for ajax url getting and quick display...  function JQueryDialog(url){ 
  $("#dialog").remove(); 
  $("body").append("<div id='dialog' title='www.mysite.com'></div>");  
  $("#dialog").load(url).dialog({   
   resizable: false,   
   width: 770,   
   height: 470,   
   modal: true, 
   buttons : { 
    "Close" : function (){ 
     $(this).dialog("close"); 
     $("#dialog").remove(); 
    } 
   } 
  }); 
 }

Comment: Could you please explain how your myconfirm function works, line by line.  I am new to javascript and some of it I understand and some of it I do not.  THANKS

Answer (score 6):

Simple and short solution that i just tried and it works

```
  $('.confirm').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('confirm');
    $(this).text("Sure?");
    $(this).unbind();
    return false;
  });
```

then just add the class="confirm" to your a link and it works!

Comment: The .text message asks "Sure?" but doesn't give a choice of yes/no, ok/cancel.  How does the user indicate if they are "sure" or "not sure"?

Answer (score 6):

This is my solution.. i hope it helps anyone. It's written on the fly instead of copypasted so forgive me for any mistakes.

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    dialog.dialog("open");

    dialog.find(".btnConfirm").on("click", function(){
        // trigger click under different namespace so 
        // click handler will not be triggered but native
        // functionality is preserved
        $("#btn").trigger("click.confirmed");
    }
    dialog.find(".btnCancel").on("click", function(){
        dialog.dialog("close");
    }
});
```

Personally I prefer this solution :)

edit: Sorry.. i really shouldve explained it more in detail. I like it because in my opinion its an elegant solution. 
When user clicks the button which needs to be confirmed first the event is canceled as it has to be. 
When the confirmation button is clicked the solution is not to simulate a link click but to trigger the same native jquery event (click) upon the original button which would have triggered if there was no confirmation dialog. The only difference being a different event namespace (in this case 'confirmed') so that the confirmation dialog is not shown again. Jquery native mechanism can then take over and things can run as expected.
Another advantage being it can be used for buttons and hyperlinks. I hope i was clear enough.

Comment: Consider editing your post and tell the community why you prefer this solution. What makes it better for you?

Comment: I edited the post. I hope it makes more sense now. When i wrote it it seemed so clear there was no need for a comment. What a difference when i revisited it after a while... :)

Comment: A great as very clean solution! Never read about event namespaces before. Thanks for that!

Comment: BEAAUUTIFULLL!  "..but to trigger the same native jquery event (click) upon the original button.." sounds **beauutifulll!!**  Thanks for  `$("#btn").trigger("click.confirmed");`

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but here is my solution using HTML5 [data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) in MVC4:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required" data-url="@Url.Action("UndoAllPendingChanges", "Home")">
  Are you sure about this?
</div>
```

JS code:

```js
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,              
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        "Confirm": function () {
            window.location.href = $(this).data('url');
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#TheIdOfMyButton").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: I like this solution, thanks. Easy to understand, and works for me. I didn't use the @Url.Action part, but it works with a URL generated by my server-side MVC (PHP/Symfony2).

Answer (score 3):

Will this do?

```
$("ul li a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#confirmDialog').show();

  var delete_path = $(this).attr('href');

  $('#confirmDialog a.ok').unbind('click'); //  just in case the cancel link 
                                            //  is not the  only way you can
                                            //  close your dialog
  $('#confirmDialog a.ok').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     window.location.href = delete_path;
  });

});

$('#confirmDialog a.cancel').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#confirmDialog').hide();
   $('#confirmDialog a.ok').unbind('click');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I am sure I will test it out (and yet it looks functional). One of the problem I saw from many answers here is the lack of generality. If the page has another set of controls (or links or so on) that needed confirmation, seems we need multiple declaration on the interaction / action.

The old javascript way, ie, href="javascript:confirm('link_url');" is simple and elegant and suits all similar cases. Of course the javascript method is too obstrusive that people w/o javascript will entirely miss the link. 

Once again thx for the great reply.

Answer (score 3):

As above. Previous posts got me on the right track. This is how I've done it.
The idea is to have an image next to every row in the table (generated by PHP script from database). When an image is clicked, the user would get redirected to the URL, and as a result, the appropriate record would be deleted from the database while showing some data related to the clicked record within jQuery UI Dialog.

The JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#confirmDelete").dialog({
    modal: true,
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: false
  });
});

function confirmDelete(username, id) {
  var delUrl = "/users/delete/" + id;
  $('#confirmDelete').html("Are you sure you want to delete user: '" + username + "'");
  $('#confirmDelete').dialog('option', 'buttons', {
    "No": function () {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "Yes": function () {
      window.location.href = delUrl;
    }
  });
  $('#confirmDelete').dialog('open');
}
```

Dialog div:

```
<div id="confirmDelete" title="Delete User?"></div>
```

Image link:

```
<img src="img/delete.png" alt="Delete User" onclick="confirmDelete('<?=$username;?>','<?=$id;?>');"/>
```

This way you can pass over the PHP loop values into the dialog box.
The only downside is using GET method to actually perform the action.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$("ul li a").click(function() {

el = $(this);
$("#confirmDialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, resizable:false,
                             draggable:true,
                             modal: true,
                             buttons: { "Ok": function() {
                                el.parent().remove();
                                $(this).dialog("close"); } }
                           });
$("#confirmDialog").dialog("open");

return false;
});
```

I have tested it at this html:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Hi 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hi 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hi 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hi 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

It removes the whole li element, you can adapt it at your needs.

Answer (score 2):

(As of 03/22/2016, the download on the page linked to doesn't work. I'm leaving the link here in case the developer fixes it at some point because it's a great little plugin. The original post follows. An alternative, and a link that actually works: [jquery.confirm](https://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/).)

It may be too simple for your needs, but you could try this [jQuery confirm plugin](http://zoomq.qiniudn.com/ZQScrapBook/ZqFLOSS/data/20091125002853/). It's really simple to use and does the job in many cases.

Comment: The link leads me to a linked-in profile. Seems you can't see the plugin unlesse you are a premium linked-in member.

Comment: I updated the link so it works again. The developer must be redirecting the old link to her LinkedIn profile.  If she changes it again then just google it using "jquery confirm plugin nadia".

Comment: Thanks! While I have already implemented my version now, I still will have a look.

Comment: the link is dead again

Answer (score 1):

As much as I hate to use eval, it seemed like the easiest way for me, without causing a lot of problems depending on different circumstances. Similar to the javascript settimeout function.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:confirm('do_function(params)');">Confirm</a>
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirm" style="display:none;">
    <p>Are you sure you want to do this?</p>
</div>
<script>
function confirm(callback){
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                eval(callback)
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

function do_function(params){
    console.log('approved');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this myself and ended up with a solution, that is similar to several answers here, but implemented slightly differently. I didn't like many pieces of javascript, or a placeholder div somewhere. I wanted a generalized solution, that could then be used in HTML without adding javascript for each use. Here is what I came up with (this requires jquery ui):

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

  $("a.confirm").button().click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    var content = $(this).attr("title");
    var title = $(this).attr("alt");

    $('<div>' + content + '</div>'). dialog({
      draggable: false,
      modal: true,
      resizable: false,
      width: 'auto',
      title: title,
      buttons: {
        "Confirm": function() {
          window.location.href = target;
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

  });

});
```

And then in HTML, no javascript calls or references are needed:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"
   class="confirm"
   alt="Confirm test"
   title="Are you sure?">Test</a>
```

Since the title attribute is used for the div content, the user can even get the confirmation question by hovering over the button (which is why i didn't user the title attribute for the tile). The title of the confirmation window is the content of the alt tag. The javascript snip can be included in a generalized .js include, and simply by applying a class you have a pretty confirmation window.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but this was my first time I had to use a confirmation dialog. I think this is the shortest way to do it.

```
$(element).onClick(function(){ // This can be a function or whatever, this is just a trigger
  var conBox = confirm("Are you sure ?");
    if(conBox){ 
        // Do what you have to do
    }
    else
        return;
});
```

I hope you like it :)

Answer (score 1):

Very popular topic and google finds this for "jquery dialog close which event was clicked" query. My solution handles YES,NO,ESC_KEY,X events properly. I want my callback function be called no matter how dialog was disposed.

```
function dialog_YES_NO(sTitle, txt, fn) {
    $("#dialog-main").dialog({
        title: sTitle,
        resizable: true,
        //height:140,
        modal: true,
        open: function() { $(this).data("retval", false); $(this).text(txt); },
        close: function(evt) {
            var arg1 = $(this).data("retval")==true;
            setTimeout(function() { fn(arg1); }, 30);
        },
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() { $(this).data("retval", true); $(this).dialog("close"); },
            "No": function()  { $(this).data("retval", false); $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });
}
- - - - 
dialog_YES_NO("Confirm Delete", "Delete xyz item?", function(status) {
   alert("Dialog retval is " + status);
});
```

It's easy to redirect browser to a new url or perform something else on function retval.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li a").live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                    .html('<div><h6>Are you sure about this?</h6></div>')
                    .dialog({
                        modal: true, title: 'Delete message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                        width: 'auto', modal: true, resizable: false,
                        buttons: {
                            Confirm: function () {
                                // $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');                                
                                // $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();

                                $(this).dialog("close");

                                window.location.reload();
                            },
                            No: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                        Cancel: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    });

            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this to use on link-buttons within an ASP.NET Gridview (GridView Control build in Commands)
So the "Confirm" action in the dialog needs to activate a script generated by the Gridview control at run-time. this worked for me:

```
 $(".DeleteBtnClass").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var inlineFunction = $(this).attr("href") + ";";
     $("#dialog").dialog({
         buttons: {
             "Yes": function () {
                 eval(inlineFunction); // eval() can be harmful!
             },
                 "No": function () {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: **eval() can be harmful!** By the way, I have to cite this part of your code: `var inlineFunction = $(this).attr("href") + ";"; /* ... */ eval(inlineFunction);` This doesn't make sense at all!

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Not enough rep to comment but BineG's answer works perfectly in resolving postback issues with ASPX pages as highlighted by Homer and echo.  In honor, here's a variation using a dynamic dialog.

```
$('#submit-button').bind('click', function(ev) {
    var $btn = $(this);
    ev.preventDefault();
    $("<div />").html("Are you sure?").dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Confirmation",
        buttons: [{
            text: "Ok",
            click: function() {
                $btn.trigger("click.confirmed");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }, {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    }).show();  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation of the above where it checks if the control is either a 'asp:linkbutton' or 'asp:button' which renders as two different html controls. Seems to work just fine for me but haven't tested it extensively.

```
        $(document).on("click", ".confirm", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var btn = $(this);
            $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'buttons', {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    if (btn.is("input")) {                            
                        var name = btn.attr("name");
                        __doPostBack(name, '')
                    }
                    else {
                        var href = btn.attr("href");
                        window.location.href = href;
                    }
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            });

            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I see this as a recurrent requirement in many views of many ASP.Net MVC applications.

That's why I defined a model class and a partial view:

```
using Resources;

namespace YourNamespace.Models
{
  public class SyConfirmationDialogModel
  {
    public SyConfirmationDialogModel()
    {
      this.DialogId = "dlgconfirm";
      this.DialogTitle = Global.LblTitleConfirm;
      this.UrlAttribute = "href";
      this.ButtonConfirmText = Global.LblButtonConfirm;
      this.ButtonCancelText = Global.LblButtonCancel;
    }

    public string DialogId { get; set; }
    public string DialogTitle { get; set; }
    public string DialogMessage { get; set; }
    public string JQueryClickSelector { get; set; }
    public string UrlAttribute { get; set; }
    public string ButtonConfirmText { get; set; }
    public string ButtonCancelText { get; set; }
  }
}
```

And my partial view:

```
@using YourNamespace.Models;

@model SyConfirmationDialogModel

<div id="@Model.DialogId" title="@Model.DialogTitle">
  @Model.DialogMessage
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#@Model.DialogId").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true
    });

    $("@Model.JQueryClickSelector").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var sTargetUrl = $(this).attr("@Model.UrlAttribute");

      $("#@Model.DialogId").dialog({
        buttons: {
          "@Model.ButtonConfirmText": function () {
            window.location.href = sTargetUrl;
          },  
          "@Model.ButtonCancelText": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }
      });

      $("#@Model.DialogId").dialog("open");
    });
  });
</script>
```

And then, every time you need it in a view, you just use @Html.Partial (in did it in section scripts so that JQuery is defined):

```
@Html.Partial("_ConfirmationDialog", new SyConfirmationDialogModel() { DialogMessage = Global.LblConfirmDelete, JQueryClickSelector ="a[class=SyLinkDelete]"})
```

The trick is to specify the JQueryClickSelector that will match the elements that need a confirmation dialog. In my case, all anchors with the class SyLinkDelete but it could be an identifier, a different class etc. For me it was a list of:

```
<a title="Delete" class="SyLinkDelete" href="/UserDefinedList/DeleteEntry?Params">
    <img class="SyImageDelete" alt="Delete" src="/Images/DeleteHS.png" border="0">
</a>
```

Comment: ASP.Net MVC with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

So many good answers here ;)
Here is my approach. Similiar to eval() usage.

```
function functionExecutor(functionName, args){
    functionName.apply(this, args);
}

function showConfirmationDialog(html, functionYes, fYesArgs){
    $('#dialog').html(html);
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        buttons : [
            {
                text:'YES',
                click: function(){
                    functionExecutor(functionYes, fYesArgs);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                class:'green'
            },
            {
                text:'CANCEL',
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                class:'red'
            }
        ]
    });     
}
```

And the usage looks like:

```
function myTestYesFunction(arg1, arg2){
    alert("You clicked YES:"+arg1+arg2);
}

function toDoOrNotToDo(){
    showConfirmationDialog("Dialog text", myTestYesFunction, ['My arg 1','My arg 2']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box JQuery UI offers this solution:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  } );
```

HTML

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;">
 </span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

You can further customize this by providing a name for the JQuery function and passing the text/title you want displayed as a parameter.

Reference: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score -1):

Well this is the answer of your  questions...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Santa Luisa</TITLE>
<style>
    body{margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#ffffff;}
    a:link {color:black;}    
a:visited {color:black;}  
a:hover {color:red;}  
a:active {color:red;}
</style>

</HEAD>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>

    <script src="external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>

    <script src="ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script src="ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>

    <script src="ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
    <script src="ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demos.css">
    <script>
    var lastdel;
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,modal: true,closeOnEscape: true
        });

        $(".confirmLink").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var lastdel = $(this).attr("href");

        });


        $("#si").click( function() {
            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            window.location.href =lastdel;

        });
        $("#no").click( function() {
            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
        });
    });

    </script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
        var currentimgx;
        var cimgoverx=200-6;
        var cimgoutx=200;


        function overbx(obj){
        color='#FF0000';
        width='3px';
        obj.style.borderTopWidth = width;
        obj.style.borderTopColor =color;
        obj.style.borderTopStyle ='solid';

        obj.style.borderLeftWidth = width;
        obj.style.borderLeftColor =color;
        obj.style.borderLeftStyle ='solid';

        obj.style.borderRightWidth = width;
        obj.style.borderRightColor =color;
        obj.style.borderRightStyle ='solid';

        obj.style.borderBottomWidth = width;
        obj.style.borderBottomColor =color;
        obj.style.borderBottomStyle ='solid';


        currentimgx.style.width=cimgoverx+"px";
        currentimgx.style.height=cimgoverx+"px"; 

    }

    function outbx(obj){
        obj.style.borderTopWidth = '0px';   
        obj.style.borderLeftWidth = '0px';
        obj.style.borderRightWidth = '0px';
        obj.style.borderBottomWidth = '0px';

        currentimgx.style.width=cimgoutx+"px";
        currentimgx.style.height=cimgoutx+"px"; 
    }

function ifocusx(obj){
        color='#FF0000';
        width='3px';
        obj.style.borderTopWidth = width;
        obj.style.borderTopColor =color;
        obj.style.borderTopStyle ='solid';

        obj.style.borderLeftWidth = width;
        obj.style.borderLeftColor =color;
        obj.style.borderLeftStyle ='solid';

        obj.style.borderRightWidth = width;
        obj.style.borderRightColor =color;
        obj.style.borderRightStyle ='solid';

        obj.style.borderBottomWidth = width;
        obj.style.borderBottomColor =color;
        obj.style.borderBottomStyle ='solid';

    }

    function iblurx(obj){
        color='#000000';
        width='3px';
        obj.style.borderTopWidth = width;
        obj.style.borderTopColor =color;
        obj.style.borderTopStyle ='solid';

        obj.style.borderLeftWidth = width;
        obj.style.borderLeftColor =color;
        obj.style.borderLeftStyle ='solid';

        obj.style.borderRightWidth = width;
        obj.style.borderRightColor =color;
        obj.style.borderRightStyle ='solid';

        obj.style.borderBottomWidth = width;
        obj.style.borderBottomColor =color;
        obj.style.borderBottomStyle ='solid';
    }

    function cimgx(obj){
        currentimgx=obj;
    }


    function pause(millis){
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;

    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < millis);
    } 


//-->
</SCRIPT>
<div id="dialog" title="CONFERMA L`AZIONE" style="text-align:center;">
    <p><FONT  COLOR="#000000" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:22px;font-style:bold;COLOR:red;">CONFERMA L`AZIONE:<BR>POSSO CANCELLARE<BR>QUESTA RIGA ?</FONT></p>

    <p><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="SI" NAME="" id="si"> --><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="NO" NAME="" id="no"></p>
</div>



<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0" WIDTH="100%" height="100%">
<TR valign="top" align="center">
    <TD>
    <FONT COLOR="red" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:25px;font-style:bold;color:red;">Modifica/Dettagli:<font style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;font-style:bold;background-color:yellow;color:red;">&nbsp;298&nbsp;</font><font style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;font-style:bold;background-color:red;color:yellow;">dsadas&nbsp;sadsadas&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</FONT>
    </TD>
</TR>

<tr valign="top">
    <td align="center">
        <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0" WIDTH="">
        <TR align="left">

            <TD>
                <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0" WIDTH="">

                <TR align="left">
                    <TD>
                    <font style="font-sixe:30px;"><span style="color:red;">1</span></font><br><TABLE class="tabela" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="1" WIDTH="800px"><TR style="color:white;background-color:black;"><TD align="center">DATA</TD><TD align="center">CODICE</TD><TD align="center">NOME/NOMI</TD><TD  align="center">TESTO</TD><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></TR><TR align="center"><TD>12/22/2010&nbsp;</TD><TD>298&nbsp;</TD><TD>daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TD><TD><A HREF="modificarigadiario.php?codice=298"  style="font-weight:bold;color:red;font-size:30px;">Modifica</A></TD><TD><A HREF="JavaScript:void(0);"  style="font-weight:bold;color:red;font-size:30px;" onclick="$('#dialog').dialog('open');$('#dialog').animate({ backgroundColor: '#aa0000', color: '#fff', width: 250 }, 2000);lastdel='cancellarighe.php?codice=298&id=1';alert(lastdel);" class="confirmLink">Cancella</A></TD><TR align="center"><TD>22/10/2010&nbsp;</TD><TD>298&nbsp;</TD><TD>dfdsfsdfsf</TD><TD><A HREF="modificarigadiario.php?codice=298"  style="font-weight:bold;color:red;font-size:30px;">Modifica</A></TD><TD><A HREF="JavaScript:void(0);"  style="font-weight:bold;color:red;font-size:30px;" onclick="$('#dialog').dialog('open');$('#dialog').animate({ backgroundColor: '#aa0000', color: '#fff', width: 250 }, 2000);lastdel='cancellarighe.php?codice=298&id=2';alert(lastdel);" class="confirmLink">Cancella</A></TD></TABLE><font style="font-sixe:30px;"><span style="color:red;">1</span></font><br>

                    </TD>
                </TR>

                </TABLE>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>


</body>
</html>
```

make sure you have jquery 1.4.4
and jquery.ui

Comment: This is one of the ugliest codes I've seen in years. You use deprecated attributes (like `LANGUAGE="JavaScript"`), use uppercase and lowercase characters mixed, you mix plain JS codes with jQuery codes totally unnecessarily, and you set styles with JS instead of CSS (ugly and semantically incorrect), and, by the way, your style modification (with plain JS) is absolutely irrelevant regarding the original question. You should definitely shorten and beautify your code and focus on answering the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Easy way with a touch of javascript

```
$("#myButton").click(function(event) {
    var cont = confirm('Continue?');
    if(cont) {
        // do stuff here if OK was clicked
        return true;
    }
    // If cancel was clicked button execution will be halted.
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: The point was specifically to avoid using the default javascript functions alert/confirm etc., so this isn't a solution to the question.

Answer (score -3):

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="Delete(@item.id)" / >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Delete(id) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure ?") == true) {
            $.get("/Stud/StudDelete", {
                id: id
            }, function(res) {
                if (res) {
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide inside your answer what was the problem, and what you have done to solve it? An answer with only code does not explain that much. Also, there are already 27 answers to this question, so what does this answer add to what is already there?