# How to remove close button on the jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How do I remove the close button (the **X** in the top-right corner) on a dialog box created by jQuery UI?

Comment: @MikeCole The documentation is for 1.10 - I think if you want to hide the close button in any lower versions you'll need to do something like the answers below.

Comment: Use "ui-dialog-titlebar-close": "display:none;"  when we setup the jqueryui modal dialog

Answer (score 723, accepted):

I have found this worked in the end (note the third line overriding the open function which find the button and hides it):

```
$("#div2").dialog({
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog || ui).hide();
    }
});
```

To hide the close button on all dialogs you can use the following CSS too:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: `$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui).hide();` to hide the button for **this** dialog only.

Comment: @Johnldol, do you use it in the context of the Robert's answer above? It should work since `ui` is defined as a function argument. See also http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Comment: I couldn't get it to work from the ui parameter either. I ended up using: 

$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", $(this).parent()).hide();

Comment: why not use `$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide()`

Comment: @Anton Just want to point out that just specifying 'ui' does not work.  you have to use 'ui.dialog'. so the correct line would be $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog).hide();

Comment: @Bradley it worked for me using `ui` only. `ui.dialog` didn't. Tested on IE8/Firefox3.6.

Comment: @Carcamano interesting.  I'm betting its a version thing with jqui.  Unfortunately, I don't know what version I was using at the time of my test.

Comment: @Bradley. ui didn't work for me, ui.dialog did but applied on each instances. To have ot working applied to only the one the open function is defined for I had to do this: $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", this.parentNode).hide();

Comment: `open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }`

Comment: Was struggling with this also: `open: function(event, ui) { $((event.target)).parent('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide(); }`

Comment: @Nabab - This worked for the targetted instance. Good work.. $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", this.parentNode).hide();

Comment: Can anyone explain the discrepancies on `ui`?  Why `ui` or `ui.dialog` or `$(this).parent`.  Better yet, can anyone point us to JQuery UI documentation describing what to expect as values for `event` and `ui`?

Comment: hiding it does not prevent it from receiving keypress events.  hitting enter could still close the dialog.  why not .remove()?

Comment: I'm using this successfully, but when I also use $(document).tooltip() I find that the "close" tooltip intermittently shows up. Anyone know how to prevent it completely?

Comment: I prefer $(this).parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); to  $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", $(this).parent()).hide()

Comment: Using $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css('display','none') works better than hide().  The answer offereed by @David on Mar 14, 2011 is much more reliable and easier to use across multiple dialogs.

Comment: Per the documentation - http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open - "Note: The ui object is empty but included for consistency with other events." So I don't see how (ui.dialog || ui) would ever be a good context.  This is apparent when you open a dialog within a dialog, it is selecting all open dialogs.  I ended up with the same as Hans: $(this).parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();

Comment: Note that if you have autoOpen: true then this doesn't work, use David or Salman A's answer instead

Comment: @jedierikb I'm surprised your solution does not have many up votes. Yours was THE solution for me.

Comment: We were resolving deferred objects within the dialog button click handlers. That was happening before we were closing the dialog. Resolving the deferred was initiating opening another dialog which was leading to the error.

Comment: in my case, I was not able to access ui.dialog so I used $.ui.dialog

Answer (score 373):

Here is another option just using CSS that does not over ride every dialog on the page.

The CSS

```
.no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {display: none }
```

The HTML

```
<div class="selector" title="No close button">
    This is a test without a close button
</div>
```

The Javascript.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ dialogClass: 'no-close' });
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/djquery/AGZKF/)

Comment: I like this approach because I can use it alongside things like: .noTitleDlg .ui-dialog-titlebar {display:none}
in CSS to build up the way I want my dialog to appear and behave and then just set the dialogClass accordingly.

Comment: very clean solution... +1 for not involving additional js functionality to remove the button.

Comment: Great idea. Comes in handy to target a specific dialog in situations where you use the same open method for all dialogs, and it is not very practical to change it for a specific instance.

Comment: My favorite solution.  I was thinking something like this would be the best approach.  Thanks for having it already coded up here.  Building upon this, I like to use this variation which will take the class attribute of the dialog's content div, into which I can put the "no-close" class: `dialogClass : $("#my-dialog-id").attr("class"),`

Comment: This solution allows closing with escape, if you want to prevent closing on escape use:
```$( ".selector" ).dialog({ dialogClass: 'no-close' , closeOnEscape: false,});```

Answer (score 128):

the "best" answer will not be good for multiple dialogs.  here is a better solution.

```
open: function(event, ui) { 
    //hide close button.
    $(this).parent().children().children('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
},
```

Comment: This is more complicated than you need. `$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", $(this).parent()).hide();`

Comment: @KevinPanko your suggestion works well when using the example provided by the jquery ui demo site with ASP.NET v2.0 in an .aspx page. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html

Comment: .closest('.ui-dialog') is better than assuming a parent.

Answer (score 90):

You can use CSS to hide the close button instead of JavaScript:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close{
    display: none;
}
```

If you don't want to affect all the modals, you could use a rule like

```
.hide-close-btn .ui-dialog-titlebar-close{
    display: none;
}
```

And apply `.hide-close-btn` to the top node of the dialog

Comment: This answer was easy and straightforward.  It applies, however, only if you wish to disable the button for all dialogs.

Comment: @MarkBrittingham You can just apply a custom CSS class to your modal and to the selector, then this will apply to whoever you want

Answer (score 54):

As shown on the official [page](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) and suggested by David:

Create a style:

```
.no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, you can simply add the no-close class to any dialog in order to hide it's close button:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    buttons: [{
        text: "OK",
        click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 42):

I think this is better.

```
open: function(event, ui) {
  $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
}
```

Comment: Issue is it occasionally  hides close button for other dialogues as well. how to prevent that .

Comment: Even Using 
open: function(event, ui) {
  $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').show();
}
doesn't work.

Answer (score 36):

Once you have called `.dialog()` on an element, you can locate the close button (and other dialog markup) at any convenient time without using event handlers:

```
$("#div2").dialog({                    // call .dialog method to create the dialog markup
    autoOpen: false
});
$("#div2").dialog("widget")            // get the dialog widget element
    .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close") // find the close button for this dialog
    .hide();                           // hide it
```

Alternate method:

Inside dialog event handlers, `this` refers to the element being "dialogged" and `$(this).parent()` refers to the dialog markup container, so:

```
$("#div3").dialog({
    open: function() {                         // open event handler
        $(this)                                // the element being dialogged
            .parent()                          // get the dialog widget element
            .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close") // find the close button for this dialog
            .hide();                           // hide it
    }
});
```

FYI, dialog markup looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable">
    <!-- ^--- this is the dialog widget -->
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        <span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-dialog">Dialog title</span>
        <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" style="height: 200px; min-height: 200px; width: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
        <!-- ^--- this is the element upon which .dialog() was called -->
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Demos here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/3r8fC/)

Comment: Great!! This allows showing/hiding of the close button after the dialog has already been initialized.

Answer (score 29):

Robert MacLean's answer did not work for me.

This however does work for me:

```
$("#div").dialog({
   open: function() { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#div2").dialog({
   closeOnEscape: false,
   open: function(event, ui) { $('#div2').parent().find('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();}
});
```

Answer (score 9):

None of the above works. The solution that really works is:

```
$(function(){
  //this is your dialog:
  $('#mydiv').dialog({
    // Step 1. Add an extra class to our dialog to address the dialog directly. Make sure that this class is not used anywhere else:
    dialogClass: 'my-extra-class' 
  })
  // Step 2. Hide the close 'X' button on the dialog that you marked with your extra class
  $('.my-extra-class').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').css('display','none');
  // Step 3. Enjoy your dialog without the 'X' link
})
```

Please check if it works for you.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to hide the button is to filter it with it's data-icon attribute:

```
$('#dialog-id [data-icon="delete"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 6):

I catch the close event of the dialog box. This code then removes the `<div>` (`#dhx_combo_list`):

```
open: function(event, ui) { 
  //hide close button.
  $(this).parent().children().children('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click(function(){
    $("#dhx_combo_list").remove();
  });
},
```

Answer (score 6):

http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/aWyNn/

```
$('#yourdiv').                 // Get your box ...
  dialog().                    // ... and turn it into dialog (autoOpen: false also works)
  prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar'). // Get title bar,...
  find('a').                   // ... then get the X close button ...
  hide();                      // ... and hide it
```

Answer (score 6):

For the deactivating the class, the short code:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
```

may be used.

Answer (score 6):

The close button added by the Dialog widget has the class 'ui-dialog-titlebar-close', so after your initial call to .dialog(), you can use a statement like this to remove the close button again:
It works..

```
$( 'a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close' ).remove();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".ui-button-icon-only").hide();
```

Comment: You should be able to use straight CSS here instead of JS if you're only hiding the icon. All `.hide()` does is set `display:none` in CSS, so `$(".ui-button-icon-only").hide();` is functionally equivalent to `.ui-button-icon-only { display: none; }`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also remove your header line:

`<div data-role="header">...</div>`

which removes the close button.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way to achieve: (Do this in your `Javascript`)

```
$("selector").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {   // It'll hide Close button
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
    },
    closeOnEscape: false,        // Do not close dialog on press Esc button
    show: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 500
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 200
    },
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.querySelector('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').style.display = 'none'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I found I was doing this in several places in my app, I wrapped it in a plugin:

```
(function ($) {
   $.fn.dialogNoClose = function () {
      return this.each(function () {
         // hide the close button and prevent ESC key from closing
         $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
         $(this).dialog("option", "closeOnEscape", false);
      });
   };
})(jQuery)
```

Usage Example:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ /* lots of options */ }).dialogNoClose();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of one-liners (where they work!). Here is what works for me:

```
$("#dialog").siblings(".ui-dialog-titlebar").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this pure CSS line? 
I find this the cleanest solution for a dialog with given Id:

```
.ui-dialog[aria-describedby="IdValueOfDialog"] .ui-dialog-titlebar-close { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for jQuery UI 1.12. I added the following configuration setting for 'classes' option

```
        classes: {
            'ui-dialog-titlebar-close': 'hidden',
        },
```

the whole dialog initialization looks like this:

```
ConfirmarSiNo(titulo, texto, idPadre, fnCerrar) {
    const DATA_RETORNO = 'retval';
    $('confirmar-si-no').dialog({
        title: titulo,
        modal: true,
        classes: {
            'ui-dialog-titlebar-close': 'hidden',
        },
        appendTo: `#${idPadre}`,
        open: function fnOpen() { $(this).text(texto); },
        close: function fnClose() {
            let eligioSi = $(this).data(DATA_RETORNO) == true;
            setTimeout(function () { fnCerrar(eligioSi); }, 30);
        },
        buttons: {
            'Si, por favor': function si() { $(this).data(DATA_RETORNO, true); $(this).dialog("close"); },
            'No, gracias': function no() { $(this).data(DATA_RETORNO, false); $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });
}
```

I use following script call to show it:

```
ConfirmarSiNo('Titulo',
              '¿Desea actualizar?',
              idModalPadre,
              (eligioSi) => {
                            if (eligioSi) {
                                this.$tarifa.val(tarifa.tarifa);
                                this.__ActualizarTarifa(tarifa);
                            }
                        });
```

whithin Html body I have the following div that contains the dialog:

```
<div class="modal" id="confirmar-si-no" title="" aria-labelledby="confirmacion-label">
    mensaje
</div>
```

final result is:

[image]

function 'ConfirmarSiNo' is based on '[Whome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185565/whome)' answer on post [How to implement “confirmation” dialog in Jquery UI dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887029/how-to-implement-confirmation-dialog-in-jquery-ui-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using [DialogExtend](https://plugins.jquery.com/dialogextend/) `jQuery Extension`, you can use the `closable` option to manage this feature as well as many other tweaks that this decent extension provides.

Note, if you are already using `DialogExtend`, any of the aforementioned Dialog CSS hacks will get clobbered by `DialogExtend` when initialized.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the close button with the code below. There are other options as well which you might fight useful.

```
$('#dialog-modal').dialog({
    //To hide the Close 'X' button
    "closeX": false,
    //To disable closing the pop up on escape
    "closeOnEscape": false,
    //To allow background scrolling
    "allowScrolling": true
    })
//To remove the whole title bar
.siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
```