# Disable 'X' button in top-right of Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove close button on jQueryUI Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog)

I'm trying to make a dialog that requires a user to agree to terms before continuing, and don't want to allow the user to just click the 'X' in the top right corner of the dialog to close. I'd like to require that the user click 'I agree'.

Is there any way to disable the 'X' in the dialog?

**Clarification:** I'm just using the standard jQuery UI dialog: $.dialog().

Comment: If the person disabled Javascript they will never see it, I recommend you use an HTML page with Post Form.

Comment: Which standard jQuery dialog?

Comment: @Michale B. who disables js anymore? I think we live in a world where it's safe to say "hi, you don't have js turned on, our site won't work for you!"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using jQuery UI.

If so, attach a beforeClose event handler and return false from it if the Agree button hasn't been clicked. You can also use CSS to set the X button to `{display: none}`

```
var agreed = false; //has to be global
$("something").dialog({
    buttons: {
        'Apply': function () {
            agreed = true;
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    beforeClose: function () {
        return agreed;
    }
});
```

Comment: it should have a semicolon, in place of the comma, between 'Apply' and function().

Answer (score 62):

I found this on another post, hopes it helps, it worked for me:

```
$("#div2").dialog({
   closeOnEscape: false,
   open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
});
```

This is the link:

[How to remove close button on the jQuery UI dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog)

Answer (score 13):

If your dialog is a regular popup window, it is not possible to prevent the user from closing the window.

You could use a jQuery modal dialog plugin, such as [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/).

Note, however, that you cannot prevent the user from closing the main window either.

---

**EDIT**: If you're using the jQuery UI dialog, you could add the following CSS rule:

```
#someId .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    display: none;
}
```

You shouldalso set the `closeOnEscape` to `false`.

---

Also, why are you **forcing** the user to click `I Agree`?
Why can't you treat a closed window as if the you disagreed?

Answer (score 3):

As far as your task of disallowing the user to click the X, I would recommend one of a few approaches:

1. use a CSS rule to set the display for that button to 'none'.  Using Firebug's Inspect mode, you should be able to look at the  tag that the jQuery UI dialog places there and add a CSS rule for it.  If it's display is none, the user shouldn't be able to click it.
2. Similarly, attach a jQuery .click() event that does nothing, and returns false to stop the event propagation (I have never actually done this one, but it should work).
3. You could attach a function to the dialog's beforeClose() event that would allow you to prevent the dialog from closing if the user hadn't clicked "I Agree"
4. Most complicated of all, but useful if you want to have similar dialogs or make other functional changes, you could subclass the jQuery UI dialog by creating a jQuery UI plugin that internally instantiates the dialog then modifies the default behavior by applying CSS rules or attaching events as described above.

Hope one of those gets you going in the right direction...

Answer (score 3):

Noticed that the div created for the dialog's titlebar has an aria-labelledby attribute that references your dialog (ui-dialog-title-{yourDialogName}), so I just hid the "x" with the following CSS:

```
div.ui-dialog[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-myDialog"] a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    display: none;
}
```

I also set closeOnEscape to false to prevent that.

Answer (score 3):

I add had a related issue:  do a reload after user clicks the X to close in a specific dialog window, no reload in other windows.  I added to jQuery dialog function in .js:

```
.click(function(i){ jQuery('span.ui-dialog-title').each(function(index) {


    if (jQuery(this).text() == '/**Title String Here**/') {

        a.close(i); location.reload(true); 

    } else {

        a.close(i);
    }

  });
return false})
```

This looks for the title in the span text, and does reload upon close, otherwise close with no reload.

Answer (score 3):

Just a complement to Michael Meadows's answer.  If you have multiple form and don't want to have the variable global, you can just add an attribute to the form DOM element.  Something like :

```
$('#yourForm').dialog(
 open : function(){
   $('#yourForm').attr('agreed', false);
 },
 beforeClose : function(){
   return $('#yourForm').attr('agreed') == 'true';
 },
 buttons:{'OK':function(){
        $('#yourForm').attr('agreed', true);        
        $(this).dialog('close');
    },
    'Cancel' : function(){
        $('#yourForm').attr('agreed', false);
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
 }
);
```

I think you have to compare with 'true' and not only true since I think that attr are stored as string.  but I am not sure about that....

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `alert`, perhaps you should consider `confirm` instead:

```
if (!confirm("Click OK to confirm that you agree to the terms and conditions.")) {
    // they didn't click OK
} else {
    // they did.
}
```

Or, use [a plugin](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) like SLaks mentioned