# How to remove the upper right close button

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, redirect, modal-dialog

I need to kill the close 'x' button at the top of a jQuery UI modal dialog box. I have a modal that opens with an OK button that redirects to the site. The site behind the modal is in an iframe. When the user agrees to the statement in the dialog box and clicks the 'OK' button, it redirects to the site that is outside the iframe. If the user clicks on the 'x', it goes to the iframe site, which I do not want to have happen.

I need the modal to work as a one-way to the site it goes to. It basically forces the user to accept the user agreement.

I would post code, but its an intranet site.

Thanks everyone for your help!

EDIT: This site is a government intranet portal, not a commercial site. So the goal is NOT to trap a user into the site, but rather to let the user know that the use of this site is restricted and to make sure you understand and accept the user agreement or you cannot use the site.

Comment: You should provide them a way to cancel instead of forcing it. This is better coding and a better user experience.

Comment: So, if they cancel, I would need the browser to close. It's not a commercial site, it's a government intranet portal. So there's no commercial interest to keep the user trapped there. My apologies, I should've explained this in the question.

Comment: Ah, okay. I don't use prebuilt jQuery modal boxes, so can't answer, but especially if the iframed site is supposed to be inaccessible, I'd encourage you to see if there's a way this can be taken out of the realm of javascript and handled by an intermediate page. Javascript is ultimately pretty fragile, and any content delivered to a page is ultimately accessible. Not trying to be down on everything, but I'm not entirely sure what's going on on your page, and it sounds avoidable, is all.

Comment: Understood. Maybe instead of an iframed page, no page at all. Or a lead-in page with the user agreement on it. Either way, I'm rethinking the entry now. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove close button on jQueryUI Dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not style it to not display at all? Add this line to stylesheet:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close { display: none }
```

Comment: This works, but the hyperlink is still there. So  if I mouse over the spot I can still click on it. If you go into the js and look for the hyperlink reference and delete it, it disappears completely. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event on `open` to remove the close button.

Using firebug I found that the CSS class for the `<a>` element is `ui-dialog-titlebar-close`.