# Best way to remove the close button on jQuery UI dialog box widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button

What's the best way to remove the close button on the jQuery UI dialog box?

I do not wish people to be able to close the dialog box.

I'm covering it on the code angle by handling:

```
closeOnEscape: false,
beforeclose: function (event, ui) { return false; }
```

I'm trying not to need to write script to grap the class / id of the close button and then hide it manually. And I'd rather not change the CSS manually either, as the dialog box may have situations where it needs the close button.

I'd prefer to do it the dialog config somehow, but either I can't figure out how to do it or the dialog box doesn't allow for it at all.

Any suggestions on how to configure the dialog box?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove close button on jQueryUI Dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I found this to be a good solution

```
$("#myDialogID").dialog({
    closeOnEscape: false,
    beforeClose: function (event, ui) { return false; },
    dialogClass: "noclose"
});
```

Not altering the existing styles, instead adding a new bit:

```
.noclose .ui-dialog-titlebar-close
{
    display:none;
}
```

Adding the class ended up being quite an elegant method, as i'm "classing" the dialog as one that cannot be closed.

Comment: This is an extremely elegant solution. Much appreciated!

Comment: Good edit @bishop, at the time of writing "beforeclose" was still kicking around in ye'olden days :-) https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/b42125af4350eda14a6b15bb71f8dd336858fbd8/

Answer (score 4):

I found another solution, works for me:

```
$("#divID").dialog({
   closeOnEscape: false,
   open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
});
```