# Jquery popup window without close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How do I create a jQuery popup window without close button? 
Please see my code below.

```
$('#addNewRecord').dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 570,
        bgiframe: true,
        resizable: false,
        height:490,
        modal: true
    }
    );
```

Could anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer [How to remove close button on the jQuery UI dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog)

Answer (score 1):

Or how about [Best way to remove the close button on jQuery UI dialog box widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566765/best-way-to-remove-the-close-button-on-jquery-ui-dialog-box-widget)

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery dialog, so simply add the below code

`jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();` or

`$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();`

within the jQuery(document).ready();