# Disable close button in Jquery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove close button on jQueryUI Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog)

I am getting some problem to disable close button in JQuery UI Dialog.

My code is like bellow.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#dialog").dialog({ 
            modal: true,
            width:800
     });
});
```

Thanx in Advance

Comment: what are these "some problem"?

Comment: I was not getting how to disable the close button.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this It ll work..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({  
        open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
        modal: true,
        width:800
    });
});
```

Comment: Can't believe this isn't an option in creating the dialog!