# Jquery put a popup until the whole page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery put a popup until the whole page is loaded
and doesn't allows to click outside
any help encouraged.
Thanks in advance

Comment: show some code would be very nice of you.

Comment: is that a request or a problem?

Comment: Request. And I don't think anycode will help. Its just like u imaginr a simple jquery code and doesnt allows to see it until the pages loads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without jQuery, also you can write some code using jQuery to just make sure that the page is ready.

You can add a big div in the first lines of your page html:

```
<head></head>
<html>
 <body>
   <div class="bigFullScreen"></div>
   .......... the rest of the page html
 </body>
</html>
```

And in javascript:

```
$(function () {
   $('.bigFullScreen').hide();
});
```

OR:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.bigFullScreen').hide();
});
```

The previous html and jQuery will make sure that the big div will appear the first thing and just when all the html of the page is rendered the jQuery function will hide it.

**UPDATE:** You can also wait untill all the html including all the images get ready:
http://amrelgarhy.com/blog/how-to-tell-when-images-have-loaded/

Comment: Thanks but not quite exactly what I wanted but this will be helpful at many other places. I worked it out myself. But still thanks for help :D

Comment: Well its like u create centred div with high zindex and don't allow user to close it. And then just use the hide function to hide it. Won't be able to give complete code atm cus using mobile.will give 10 to 13 hours later :D

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using a [JQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and setting [`modal`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) to true.

[How to remove close button on the jQuery UI dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog) has information on "locking down" the dialog. You'll need to set [`CloseOnEscape`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-closeOnEscape) to false too.

Comment: Thats not a problem my freind. But I want that it should like not allow user to close it or click out until it closses automatically

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog for how to do that, you'll need to set the close on escape option to false too.