# Overlay progress bar with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to display a progress bar that "overlays" the page, disabling other actions while it's running, kind of like an alert (except you couldn't exit it by clicking anything).  What's a fast way to do this in jQuery?

I already have the image picked out-- an animated progress bar.  Just need a way to properly overlay it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can easily implement your own overlay.

```
#overlay {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  opacity: 0.2; /* also -moz-opacity, etc. */
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Then display `<div id="overlay"><img src="/path/to/your/image"/></div>` when your page is loading, or whenever you want to display it.

Comment: will this prevent users from doing other things while it's showing?

Comment: It will. It displays a `div` that covers the whole page. Make sure there's nothing that you want to cover that has a higher `z-index`. Also, this will just prevent users from clicking on covered items, it can't be used as a security measure.

Answer (score 3):

I think the jQuery UI [Modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) is what you're looking for. It overlays the rest of the screen, until a user dismisses the dialog. You can add your progress bar inside the dialog itself or add the jQuery UI [progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) as well, if you find out that works better. That also has a lot of options that you may find handy.

If you want this to be truly a "can't-do-anything-until-this-finishes" type of dialog, then you can also take out the closing "X" using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog/897393#897393).

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)? This is what we use it for.