# How to remove x button from jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I have an application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable3.php) where if you don't do anything for about 20 seconds, it will display a idle timeout plugin message stating if you want to continue or log off.

The problem is that it displays a x button on the top button of the corner and if the user clicks on the x button, the message goes but in the tab the timer still continues.

So what my question is that how can I remove the x button in the top corner of the message?

Below is the code for the application:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()

{

    $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        'Yes, Keep Working': function(){
            // Just close the dialog. We pass a reference to this
            // button during the init of the script, so it'll automatically
            // resume once clicked
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'No, Logoff': function(){
            // fire whatever the configured onTimeout callback is.
            $.idleTimeout.options.onTimeout.call(this);
        }
    }
});


$.idleTimeout('#dialog', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
    idleAfter: 5, // user is considered idle after 5 minutes of no movement
    pollingInterval: 60, // a request to keepalive.php (below) will be sent to the server every minute
    onTimeout: function(){

        // redirect the user when they timeout.
        window.location = "timeout.htm";

    },
    onIdle: function(){

        // show the dialog when the user idles
        $(this).dialog("open");

    },
    onCountdown: function(counter){

        // update the counter span inside the dialog during each second of the countdown
        $("#dialog-countdown").html(counter);

    },
    onResume: function(){

        // the dialog is closed by a button in the dialog
        // no need to do anything else

    }
});

});


</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Your session is about to expire!">
    <p>You will be logged off in <span id="dialog-countdown"></span> seconds.</p>
    <p>Do you want to continue your session?</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "syntax error line 1 in jquery.idletimeout.js" suggests that you're using minimized versions of the JavaScript, debugging minimized JavaScript is little more than an exercise in frustration. What happens if you use the non-minimized versions?

Comment: @muistooshort what do ou mean by minimized and non-minimized versions?

Comment: [Line 1 of `jquery.idletimeout.js`](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-idle-timeout/blob/master/src/jquery.idletimeout.js#L1) is a comment, I doubt the syntax error is there. Minimizing JavaScript removes comments and whitespace to reduce the file size, the result is typically one long line of JavaScript.

Comment: I have minimize javascript by removing the comments but no difference

Comment: I'm guessing you included jQuery AFTER idletimeout... Just guessing... jQuery has gotta go first

Comment: No, I have included jquery above the idletimout

Comment: @user1421767 next time open a new question, don't completely revamp with an edit. It makes comments and answers confusing when the entire scope of the question changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoou can hide the X when opening the dialog.

```
$("#div2").dialog({
   closeOnEscape: false,
   open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
});
```

[Here is the original SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Or simply put a

```
<style>
     .ui-dialog-titlebar-close { display: none ; }
</style>
```