# How to render/not render Close link of Jquery dialog box?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jquery

I have/can have only one Jquery dialog box. This dialog box has some advertisement content to the User.
On reading it, a User can avail the offer or ignore it for the time being.

User can avail the offer by clicking on Submit button inside the dialog box.
Or he can ignore it by clicking on "Remind me later" link which will close the dialog box.
Contents inside dialog box are updated through Ajax. So when Submit button is clicked,
a thank you message is shown inside the same dialog box.

When User avails the offer, "Remind me later" link would still be there. If User clicks on that, logically, dialog 
box should be shown again. But, User has already availed the offer!

How can I render or not render Close link of Jquery dialog box programatically?

Code for dialog box is below,

```
$h(document).ready(function() {

            $h("#showForm").dialog({
                 open: function(event, ui) {
                     jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').html('<span>Remind me later</span>');
                     jQuery('.ui-dialog-content').removeClass("ui-dialog-content").addClass("advertise-upgrade-content");
                 },
                duration: 800,
                height: 727,
                minWidth: 811,
                width: 811,
                position: ['middle', 154],
                zIndex: 99999999,
                modal: true,
                show: {
                    effect: 'puff',
                    duration: 400
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: 'puff',
                    duration: 400
                }

            });
        });



   <div id="showForm" height: 670px;">
    <div class="submitClass">
        <a4j:commandLink immediate="true" action="#{myBean.clickToAvail}" reRender="renderSuccess" value="Submit">
        </a4j:commandLink>
    </div>

    <h:panelGroup id="renderSuccess">
        <h:outputText value="Thank you for availing this offer">     
    </h:panelGroup>
  </div>
```

Am using `jquery.min.js`, `jquery-1.6.2.js` , `jquery-ui.min.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `open` function, make a logical check whether `Thank you` message container is visible (assuming that it's visible only if the user has availed the offer) and if it's visible, hide `close` ('Remind me later' in your case) or else, show it.

Also, you're using a very generic code to manipulate the attributes of dialogue in `open`. You should make use of the `ui` variableto make your code specific to only the *current* dialog

Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/897393/154325) for both `close` manipulation and example usage of `ui` variable

EDIT: making four changes

1) Give an id to the span

**NB:** This *still* needs to be specific to this dialog. Please refer to the thread mentioned above.

`jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').html('<span id=\'reminder\'>Remind me` later');

2) Define a boolean variable say `availed` in your bean and set it in your `clickToAvail` method

```
public void clickToAvail(){
// business logic here
this.availed = true;
}
```

3) Use `data` and `oncomplete`

```
<a4j:commandLink immediate="true" action="#{myBean.clickToAvail}" data="#{myBean.availed}" reRender="renderSuccess" value="Submit" oncomplete="removeReminder(event.data);">
        </a4j:commandLink>
```

4) Define a `removeReminder` javascript function in the `<head>` of your page

```
function removeReminder(availed){
if(availed == 'true' ||  availed == true)
$('#reminder').hide(); // or remove() decide as per your requirement
}
```

Comment: If offer is availed, I can set a `boolean` in bean. Question is how can I make a logical check whether this `boolean` is `true` or `false` in dialog box?

Comment: You update the dialog content after `Submit` click through ajax right? Can you hide the `close` on `success` of that ajax request?

Comment: Well.. that is my question. I don't know how to hide the `Close` (in my terms its called "Remind me later") based upon the value in my bean.

Comment: Can you post the submit button code? That might help us to help you! :)

Comment: I have updated my question with contents inside `showForm`. Contents inside `showForm` are shown inside dialog box and this contains Submit button.

Comment: Am getting `undefined` as the value for `availed` inside the Java Script. What could be the cause?

Comment: Which version of RichFaces are you using? RichFaces 3.x makes use of `data` instead of `event.data` I suppose