# How to remove close function that is fired on dialog close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am initialising a jQuery-UI dialog with close function defined as below:

```
$("#msg").dialog({
  width: '390',
  height: '320',
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  closeOnEscape: false,
  resizable: false,
  close: function (event, ui) { 
    window.location = "http://www.somewere.com"; 
  }
});
```

This dialog was being called from numerous places and since the logic was to always redirect after giving the user the message, so I placed it in initialisation.

Now the requirement is to change just one logic where the workflow will be on the same page.

How can I disable the close function just before opening this dialog?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
$("#msg").dialog({
  width: '390',
  height: '320',
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  closeOnEscape: false,
  resizable: false,
  close: function (event, ui) { 
    window.location = "http://www.somewere.com"; 
  },
  open: function(){
    this.close = function(){};
  }
});
```

Though, the `close` will not be disabled on before opening, it will be disabled after opening, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

write down inside close function as :

```
close:function(event, ul){
   $(this).dialog('close');
   return false;
}
```