# passing arguments to javascript function from code-behind , error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, argument-passing

in code behind :

```
    string func = "showSuccessMessage("+name+");";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "success", func, true);
```

in a js file :

```
   function showSuccessMessage(user)
   {
        $("#box").dialog({
            title:"User Registration",
            html: user.toString() + " Successfully Registered", 
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                   Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    var s = "../Pages/main.aspx";                
                    window.location = s;
                   }
        }
   });
 } // end function
```

when i try to pass the func string with no arguments every thing works out fine

when i try to append the argument into the function string i get an error from  the browser

Uncaught ReferenceError: john is not defined

(john being the value of name)
now i'm guessing the problem occurs because the way the function is registered it can't distinguish between a the variable and the value , so it is a non-defined type john

so the question stands :

how does one send arguments to a javascript function from code-behind

thanks in advance 
eran.

btw similar question :
showing something similar to what iv'e attempted

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788330/passing-arguments-to-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are writing it, it's like passing in `john` as a variable, not a string. It's like invoking

```
showSuccessMessage(john); // what you're doing in js
showSuccessMessage('john'); // what you need
```

Correct that with

```
string func = "showSuccessMessage('"+name+"');";
```

Comment: 10x allot , i knew that was the problem 
i just didn't think of putting ' ' .