# FormNavigate with confirm box yes no button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When a user leaves a JSP page, I need to display a confirmation with yes no button "You have unsaved changes. Do you want to leave it without saving?". If the user presses "ok", then the user goes to the page s/he is navigating to. Otherwise, if "no" is pressed, the user stays on the page. My code is here:

```
    var formdata_original=false;
    jQuery(".outConfirmPlugin").click(function () {

        if (formdata_original == false) {
            con();
        }
        return formdata_original;
    });
    function con() {
        $.confirm({
            'title':'',
            'message':settings.jsMessage,
            'buttons':{
                'Yes':{
                    'class':'blue',
                    'action':function () {
                        formdata_original = true;

                    }
                },
                'No':{
                    'class':'gray',
                    'action':function () {

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

I know my error is: function "`con`" and "`return formdata_original;`" - they are not synchronized. How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887029/how-to-implement-confirmation-dialog-in-jquery-ui-dialog

Answer (score 0):

try return simple value from you function, i mean

```
action':function () {
                       return true;
                    }
```

and when you call 'con' function you will be able to write

```
 formdata_original = con();
```

In this case you can not worry about sinhronize

The second option is creation global object that belongs ot window or $. So try

```
window["formdata_original"] = false
```

and in your code inside confirm dialog

```
window["formdata_original"]=true.
```

Comment: I think, as i understood from you description you need deside submit or not from. So you need in action for YES write "$('#ID_FORM').submit()" Because in currect structure of code firstly result of click will be return false, and after that your formdata_original will be changed.

Comment: in addition you are able to override event submit of the form, and on the step of confirm ation submit or not form, but in this you need return false in order to prevent bubbling.

Comment: if it is not stricted requirment of usinf confirm plugin you can consider of usinf nativ jquery plugin http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default