# Unable to create a JQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, dialog

I'm trying to get a JQuery dialog to appear and immediately got the error `$(...).dialog() doesn't exist`. My googling has revealed that this is usually caused by loading 2 different JQuery libraries but the only script tags in my file are for JQuery and Twitter Bootstrap. Here's my code (including my dialog code adapted from [How to implement "confirmation" dialog in Jquery UI dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887029/how-to-implement-confirmation-dialog-in-jquery-ui-dialog))..

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
...

<script>
$(function(){
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true
});
$(".deleteLink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        buttons : {
            "Yes" : function(){
                window.location.replace(targetUrl);
            },
            "No" : function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Is there any other reason that I might be getting this error besides loading multiple libraries or does bootstrap maybe provide interference of some kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use the `dialog()` method and properties of jQueryUI, yet you have included the Bootstrap library. To use the Bootstrap dialog, the method is called `modal()`.

[Bootstrap Modal docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Note that the properties are completely different. If you want to use the jQuery UI `dialog()` method, you would need to include the jQueryUI library, however be aware that this sometimes causes incompatibilities with Bootstrap, in both the JS and CSS.